# Merging document from other account to my google drive

Tags: google-drive

I want to add a document to my google drive(from some other person) that won't be edited by me.

I always want to have the latest revision of that document on my drive. Since its a big technical document I won't notice small changes.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the person to share the relevant file with you so that you will always get the latest version. He/She can grant you read-only access to the file, and you can also know that the file has been changed the next time you want to open it when you see the file name in bold.

Comment: What if I want to have a local copy of mine and want to verify before applying changes? like version control system?

Comment: There are revisions in Google Docs, but it can be quite tedious to make it work like version control. I can't really help on this part though, sorry about that.

Comment: @iamcreasy File revisions are also available for none Google Drive file types, such as PDF, DOCX etc. See following referece to the Google Help: http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2409045

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Actually there are file revisions for Google Drive file types, but there will be a lot as Google saves your work fairly frequently, creating a new revision on each save.

Comment: @Hydra I wanted to tell that this is also for none Google files...=). Revised my comment

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Oh haha, that should be non-Google Drive file types :D

Comment: @Hydra Only now I understand your remark. None vs. non. There goes my English....